# Stack page navigation with Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, angular-router

Is there a way to push a page in stack instead or replacing the older by the new one ?

For Instance, I have 2 pages, and I can switch page from a main menu in the sidebar. 
Each time I switch pages, this on is re-construct. Is there a way to save the full page as in Ionic ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NavigateRoot is to create new root page if you using in your menu then your page reconstruct every time when page change

NavigateForward is create child page and your first page as it is a root page so your first page not reconstruct every time

Comment: You're answer is describing how it works in Ionic, but I'd like to understand how to do the same thing in Angular 9 web app.